# QuickFIX or QuickFIX/J?

Tags: quickfix

I can develop with either C or Java.  What implementation is most stable for production use? What implementation is most actively developed?

Comment: I don't think you should select your language based on which library is most actively developed. Both work well, so use whichever language you feel more comfortable coding in.

Answer (score 5):

If you are a C developer, use the C++ library(Quickfix). Both libraries are not that difficult to grasp. I have used both of them and am currently using QuickfixJ. Give priority to that library, which uses the language you are most comfortable in. Have a go through the examples to make it easier to understand. Java examples have a default config file, but you would need to write you own config file for the C++ examples.

Comment: Using the QuickFIX C++ library from C would be a hassle. If the developer already knows Java, I'd recommend QuickFIX/J. They are both stable and ready for production use.